# Referenced project's necessary files not copied to the release folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a solution made out of 2 projects. One is `A` which is my main project and one is `B`. `A` has a reference of `B` in it. So when I build the entire solution, `B`'s `.exe` file is created in the release folder. But `B` also has reference to some `.dll` libraries that are also needed for the program to be working. And they do not appear in the release folder.

How can I change my build properties so that all the necessary files will be copied so I don't have to copy them manually every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to manually add `B`'s dependencies into `A`'s project.

A less error prone way would be to have a single common `bin` folder that both projects output to.  You set `B` to build into it and then `A` references the `B` dll from there so all the transitive dependencies are put in place just by building `B`.

Yet another approach would be to get `B` to build a Nuget package (which then describes its dependencies) and then use Nuget to add `B` as a package to `A` and it'll sort the rest out for you.

Comment: The 2nd way looks much better. Third is good, I think, when you know are done with `B`. But in my case I change its code all the time.